# Android Loading Keymaster Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat, android-sdk-tools

Since updating to the latest Android SDK tools Rev 21.1 and updating my Nexus 4 to 4.2.2, in eclipse as soon as I connect my phone I get the following error keep repeating continuously in the Log. Anyone got any ideas?

> 02-15 12:47:18.400: E/QSEECOMAPI:(3218): Error::Cannot open the file
>   /vendor/firmware/keymaster/keymaster.mdt
>
> 02-15 12:47:18.400: E/QSEECOMAPI:(3218): Error::Loading image failed
>   with ret = -1
>
> 02-15 12:47:18.400: E/QCOMKeyMaster(3218): Loading keymaster app
>   failied
>
> 02-15 12:47:18.400: E/keystore(3218): could not open keymaster device
>   in keystore (Operation not permitted)
>
> 02-15 12:47:18.400: E/keystore(3218): keystore keymaster could not be
>   initialized; exiting

Comment: For me, a reboot didn't help and I am seeing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it! This fixes the force closes in Settings (Security & VPN) but I found this also solves the keymaster issue in Eclipse.

You need root for this solution

1. Open a Terminal Emulator (If neccessary get it from Play Store for free)
2. type `su` and answer permission dialog from SuperSU or SuperUser
3. type `mount -o rw,remount /system` exactly as stated here including the spaces -> followed by enter
4. type `cd /vendor/firmware/keymaster` -> followed by enter
5. type `chmod 0644 *` -> followed by enter

Taken from http://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/18mzix/setting_crashes_after_updating_to_android_422/